# Issue in passport implementation in multi tenant laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-passport, passport-jwt

First things first, I am using [Hyn-Multi Tenant](https://tenancy.dev/docs/hyn/5.4) in my laravel 6 application Where there is a central database [connection = system] handles multiple tenant database. So far this package has helped me a lot but my application needs passport implementation for apis which is not documented in the package.

However there are [other tutorials](https://medium.com/@sadnub/hyn-tenancy-5-2-and-laravel-passport-a0d11c5a08eb) which claim passport implementation on Hyn package. I followed them and able to create access token per tenant user.

This is my config/auth.php:

```
return [
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'system-users',
    ],


'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'system',
        ],

        'staff' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'staff',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'staff',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'student',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'system' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\System\User::class,
        ],
        'staff' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Tenant\Staff::class,
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Tenant\Student::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

My each tenant models uses `UsesTenantConnection` trait

This is my EnforceTenancy middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;


class EnforceTenancy
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This is my AuthServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes(null, ['middleware' => 'tenancy.enforce']);


        // FOLLOWING CODE IS HAVING PROBLEM
        //Passport::useTokenModel(OAuthAccessToken::class);
        //Passport::useClientModel(OAuthClient::class);
        //Passport::useAuthCodeModel(OAuthCode::class);
        //Passport::usePersonalAccessClientModel(OAuthPersonalAccessClient::class);

        $this->commands([
            \Laravel\Passport\Console\InstallCommand::class,
            \Laravel\Passport\Console\ClientCommand::class,
            \Laravel\Passport\Console\KeysCommand::class,
        ]);

        \Laravel\Passport\Passport::tokensExpireIn(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10));
        \Laravel\Passport\Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(1));
    }
```

So far all good, now I am going to explain in points,

1. When I call `createToken('MyApp')` I am able to generate token on tenant db, for example:

```
if (Auth::guard('staff')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {

            $user = Auth::guard('staff')->user();

            $auth_tokens = $user->createToken('MyApp');

            $access_token = $auth_tokens->accessToken;
...
}
```

but to access login protected apis, I am sending bearer access token in header

```
window.axios
                .get("/api/meta",{
                    headers: fetchAuthHeaders()
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if(true == response.data.status) {
                        var data = response.data.data;
                        this.school.name = data.school_meta.name;
                        this.school.logo = data.school_meta.logo;
                    } else{
                        alert(response.data.message);
                    }

                })
```

**api.php**

```
Route::domain('{hostname}.lvh.me')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware('tenant.exists')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/get-oauth-secret', 'Tenant\MetaController@getOAuthData');
        Route::post('validate-login','Tenant\AuthController@validateLogin');

        Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function (){
            Route::get('meta','Tenant\AuthController@getMetaData'); //this api
        });
    });

});
```

I am getting response as `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`

2. Once the token is generated in step 1, I copy this token and paste into postman's header section and uncomment the custom passport models in AuthServiceProvider.php as shown below

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        ...


        // UNCOMMENTED FOLLOWING CUSTOM PASSPORT MODELS
        Passport::useTokenModel(OAuthAccessToken::class);
        Passport::useClientModel(OAuthClient::class);
        Passport::useAuthCodeModel(OAuthCode::class);
        Passport::usePersonalAccessClientModel(OAuthPersonalAccessClient::class);

        ...
    }
```

Now I can access `api/meta` route but while login and creating token I am getting error:

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file /home/winlappy1/Desktop/multi_tenancy/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php on line 98
```

I just want to know where I am going wrong, I know my explanation is quite ambiguous and confusing but thats all how I can explain my issue. I am ready to provide more clarification but I need to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EnforceTenancy::class
```

into the beginning of $middlewarePriority array in Kernel.php

Answer (score 1):

Also use Laravel Passport 9.1.0 which support multi Auth

Try to do this 
@AuthServiceProvider

Add this

```
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

This one is to check if the database is Tenant or not 
        $website   = \Hyn\Tenancy\Facades\TenancyFacade::website();
        if ($website != null) {
            Passport::useClientModel(PassportClient::class);
            Passport::useTokenModel(PassportToken::class);
            Passport::useAuthCodeModel(PassportAuthCode::class);
            Passport::usePersonalAccessClientModel(PassportPersonalAccessClient::class);
        }

        $this->commands([
            \Laravel\Passport\Console\InstallCommand::class,
            \Laravel\Passport\Console\ClientCommand::class,
            \Laravel\Passport\Console\KeysCommand::class,
        ]);

        \Laravel\Passport\Passport::tokensExpireIn(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10));
        \Laravel\Passport\Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(1));
    }
```

Along with these add The four models
Like this

Create four Models Which enforce the Tenants

```
   use Hyn\Tenancy\Traits\UsesTenantConnection;
    use Laravel\Passport\AuthCode;

    class PassportAuthCode extends AuthCode
    {use UsesTenantConnection;}

    use Hyn\Tenancy\Traits\UsesTenantConnection;
    use Laravel\Passport\Client;

    class PassportClient extends Client
    {use UsesTenantConnection;}

    use Hyn\Tenancy\Traits\UsesTenantConnection;
    use Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessClient;

    class PassportPersonalAccessClient extends PersonalAccessClient
    {use UsesTenantConnection;}

    use Hyn\Tenancy\Traits\UsesTenantConnection;
    use Laravel\Passport\Token;

    class PassportToken extends Token
    {use UsesTenantConnection;}
```

Also use (tenancy.enforce) middleware Enforcetenancy
'tenancy.enforce' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnforceTenancy::class, $Routemiddleware kernel.php

EnforceTenancy.php middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class EnforceTenancy
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Force the tenant routes through tenancy.enforce middleware

Also publish the new migrations and migrate:fresh as new fields are added to the new passport